# Google Chrome Command Line Help on Linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome

I need to write a little script for Google Chrome. I need it to launch a specific web-site and  scroll down to a specific spot on the page that opens. the first part is easy: (/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --new-window http://www.ustream.tv/decoraheagles).

There is a video streaming player at the bottom of the page that I need to bring up to the center, or top of the browser window.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

You could try to open http://www.ustream.tv/decoraheagles#channelFlashContent

Or find the `id` of another element on the page where you want to focus and provide that as the target.